# What monospaced font is this?

Tags: font-identification, monospace

Looking for the font used on the John Demos Architects logo. I can't seem to locate it on my own and could really use some help. Really love the monospace characters from this font. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "theloop" logo? there are not any other logo in the site at the moment.

Comment: Likely not a font but drawn just for the logo. Also, those aren't monospaced.

Comment: Wasn't referring to 'The Loop' logo. I'm actually not sure what happened to the link that I had posted. It seems like my original post was edited somehow. If you're able to google search John Demos Architects logo, you can find the original logo. Sorry, not sure how or why the original post got edited.

Comment: @Eric Does the Question look OK now? Is the first image  of interest?

Comment: @Ilan Yes, thank you. The first image is exactly what I was referring to.

Comment: @Eric ah yes, that's an entirely different typeface than the previous image! That does clarify things.

Answer (score 1):

ORCBe is pretty close, but I am pretty sure this is custom.

From the description of the work on the studio's [portfolio page](http://studiobrave.com.au/projects/john-demos-architects/) for this identity system:

> The brandmark and identity as a whole was meticulously structured and carefully crafted to accurately reflect the work they do. The visual language was stripped back, creating an unified message of understated confidence.

[ORCBe Regular](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/ocr-be/regular/) by [T-26](https://www.myfonts.com/foundry/T-26/)

[image: ORCBe Type Specimen from MyFonts.com]

Answer (score 0):

Was not able to find an exact match, but have one that is pretty close.

[Mensura Regular](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/graviton/mensura/regular/) by [Graviton](https://www.myfonts.com/foundry/Graviton/)

[image]

------------------------------------**OR**-------------------------------------------------

[Karben 105 Mono Book](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/talbot/karben-105-mono/book/) by [Talbot Type](http://www.myfonts.com/foundry/Talbot_Type/)

[image]

Comment: I think that S throws it too far off for me and the characters seem to be a bit too squared off as well. I do like some aspects of it but not quite right just yet.

Comment: Just added an update, please see above.